# ES6 Executing Method on Window Resize and Window Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-class

For the sake of clarity and to be succinct I've created this script which has to functions, to run the checkSize method on page-load and run the script when the browser resizes. My problem is that I cannot get execute the checkSize at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
class thisDiv {
    constructor() {
        this.element = $('.div');
        this.window = $(window);
        this.checkSize();
        this.events();
    }
    events() {
        this.window.resize(this.checkSize);
    }
    checkSize() {
        this.element.addClass('red');
    }
}
export default thisDiv;
```

Comment: You aren't listening (therefore not responding) to any events. investigate `.addEventListener()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @RandyCasburn: `this.window` is a jQuery object, so `this.window.resize(this.checkSize)` attaches an event listener.

Comment: `this.window.resize(this.checkSize.bind(this))`, explanation in the duplicates.